# HTML page is causing error in JMeter even if status is green

Tags: testing, automation, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

[HTML page is causing error in JMeter even if status is green , why this error is coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGpQA.jpg)

Comment: Please click on that link to see image

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

the [`Window` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is something browser-specific hence JMeter cannot execute the request properly.

You need to perform manual [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) of the dynamic parameters to replicate browser's behaviour, this way you should stop seeing errors, at least [ViewState](https://www.synacktiv.com/ressources/JSF_ViewState_InYourFace.pdf) parameter needs to be extracted from the previous response and passed to the next request, see [primefaces-jmeter-test.jmx](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michail-nikolaev/primefaces-spring-scopes/master/primefaces-jmeter-test.jmx) example test plan for details.